# What is use of @MongoId in Spring Data MongoDB over @Id?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to add Model to Mongo Db.

I know I can use @Id to avoid ObjectId creation in _id field. Now while using this I came across @MongoId from  **org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping** package.

So my question is can we use @MongoId over @Id, if yes, whats use case? Unfortunately not enough documentation available for **@MongoId**

Something like below:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoId;

import java.util.Date;

@Document
public class LeadDetails {
    @MongoId
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String mobile;
    private String landlineNumber;
    private Date contactedOn;
    private Date repliedOn;
    private String email;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some environments require a customized approach to map Id values such as data stored in MongoDB that did not run through the Spring Data mapping layer. Documents can contain _id values that can be represented either as ObjectId or as String. Reading documents from the store back to the domain type works just fine. Querying for documents via their id can be cumbersome due to the implicit ObjectId conversion. Therefore documents cannot be retrieved that way. For those cases @MongoId provides more control over the actual id mapping attempts.

[image]