# MongoRepository Delete Method

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Good afternoon fellow coders!

I have spent the last hour looking to delete a single document from my mongo "testCollection".  I would like to make use of the MongoRepository delete / deleteAll methods.  However, it does not remove the document.  It persists regardless of how many times I run the test class method.  No errors are reported and the user has readWrite permissions in the database.  I am able to run the mongo command to remove the newly created test document.

I have read about using the mongo template and create it for the deletion to be performed.  I'm happy to do that but I would rather keep it as simple as possible.

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoId;

@Data
@Document(collection = "testCollection")
public class TestClass {
    @MongoId
    private String id;

    private String name;

    public TestClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Test Class Mongo Repository interface**

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import java.util.List;

public interface TestClassRepository extends MongoRepository<TestClass, String> {
    public List<TestClass> findAllByName(String name);
    public void deleteAllByIdIn(List<TestClass> list);
}
```

**Test Method**

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.List;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class testClassTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestClassRepository testClassRepository;

    @Test
    public void crudTest() {

        TestClass testObj = new TestClass("Test");
        testClassRepository.save(testObj);

        List<TestClass> testClassList = testClassRepository.findAllByName("Test");
        Assert.assertEquals(1, testClassList.size());

        TestClass test = testClassList.get(0);
        testClassRepository.deleteAllByIdIn(testClassList);

        // Fails this assertion: Found 1, expected 0.
        Assert.assertEquals(0, testClassRepository.findAllByName("Test").size());
    }
}
```

As anyone else experienced a similar issue?  If so, how'd you go about resolving it?

Thanks!

Additions to original post:

1. Here is the mongo query generated by the MongoRepository.  It appears that it is not actually adding the "remove" mongo command to the query.  *Query: { "name" : "Test"}, Fields: {}, Sort: {}*

Comment: When u perform delete, can you post what is the command run in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a stroke of dumb luck I managed to figure out the issue.  The problem was with the type of identifier annotation I was using.  This explanation from another stackoverflow user ([What is use of @MongoId in Spring Data MongoDB over @Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466606/what-is-use-of-mongoid-in-spring-data-mongodb-over-id)) had me revisit this aspect of the model.

I switched the identifier annotation from @MongoId to @Id.  Since I have both JPA and MongoDB annotations I needed to make sure I chose the one from the *org.springframework.data.annotation* package rather than the *javax.persistance* package.

Hope this explanation helps others!