# FindById doesn't work with UUID in Mongodb SpringData

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

I try to use Mongodb with Spring Data.

I wanted to use UUID instead of ObjectId. I have followed this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-mongodb-uuid (some differences might exist because I use Kotlin). I took path 2 where I added [Entity callback](https://www.baeldung.com/java-mongodb-uuid#using-entity-callbacks). When I create a new entity it is saved to the database with UUID as I wanted. If I use mongo console I can type:

```
db.home.find({_id: UUID("18aafcf9-0c5a-46f3-84ff-1c25b00dd1ab")})
```

And I will find my entity by id.

However, when I try to do it by code it doesn't work as it should. It will always throw here ***DataOperationException(NOT_FOUND)*** because findById returns null.

```
fun findHomeById(id: String): Home {
    val home = homeRepository.findById(id)
    return home.unwrap() ?: throw DataOperationException(NOT_FOUND)
}
```

Here is repository

```
@Repository
interface HomeRepository: MongoRepository<Home, String>
```

Abstraction with id.

```
abstract class UuidIdentifiedEntity {
    @Id
    var id: UUID? = null // I tried use UUID type and String with the same result
}
```

And my home class

```
class Home(
   var address: String,
   var rooms: Int,
): UuidIdentifiedEntity()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but see if changing your @Id annotation to @MongoId fixes this. Under certain circumstances, Mongo needs to know more about a field being used for an id. @MongoId should give you more control on how the field is stored too.

[What is use of @MongoId in Spring Data MongoDB over @Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466606/what-is-use-of-mongoid-in-spring-data-mongodb-over-id)

Comment: Thank you. That solved the issue and also a good link with the explanation.